# scala: set None to Option

Tags: scala

I am trying to set the variable foo initialized as `var foo = Some(0.0)` to `None` but I am getting `None.type doesn't conform to expected type Some[Double]`. What is the correct way to specify that the variable has no value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `foo` is `Some[Double]`, you can't assign a `None.type` to it as they are different types (it doesn't matter that they share a common base). In order for you to be able to do that, you need to explicitly declare the type of `foo` to be `Option[Double]`:

```
scala> var foo: Option[Double] = Some(0.0)
foo: Option[Double] = Some(0.0)

scala> foo = None
foo: Option[Double] = None
```

Or use `Option.apply`:

```
scala> var foo = Option(0.0)
foo: Option[Double] = Some(0.0)

scala> foo = None
foo: Option[Double] = None
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuval. Declaring the type as Option[Double] casts both Some(0.0) and None to Option[Double] but without the explicit type then they are different types?

Comment: @cosmos1990 There is no casting here. Without explicit declaration of the type, the compiler attempts to infer the most specific type. You're using `Some(0.0)`, so the compiler infers `Some[Double]`, which `None` is not assignable to. But telling the compiler to view the type as the base `Option[Double]`, you allow `None` to be assigned since `None <: Option[Nothing]`, where `Nothing` is the bottom type of all types in the Scala type system.